# How can I debug a 404 on a POST request to the Server I have running on local which was built with SpringBoot?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am a beginner to using SpringBoot, therefore I am following along with this guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9SGDpanrc8U

I am at the 'Testing Post Request' section of the video.  At 1:15:00 of the video, he tests his Post request successfully.  I have taken every step that he has taken and my code is identical (to my knowledge) to his, but instead of getting back a 200, I am getting back a 404 and this is what is produced in the logs:

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx/1.23.0
Date: Thu, 04 Aug 2022 20:25:49 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 153
Connection: keep-alive

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>404 Not Found</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
            <h1>404 Not Found</h1>
        </center>
        <hr>
        <center>nginx/1.23.0</center>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'd be happy to share this demo project from my GitHub so the full code I have written can be accessed and reviewed, unless someone is able to understand my problem from the description and can provide a way for me to debug this issue or provide steps I can take to resolve the issue.  I'd really like to understand the root cause of this issue if possible.

To reproduce, I use the IntelliJ HTTP Client (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/http-client-in-product-code-editor.html)
...and do the following POST:

```
###
POST http://localhost:8080/api/v1/student
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "name": "Whitney",
  "email": "wrob@apple.com",
  "dob": "1987-12-09"
}
```

The above POST will reproduce the 404 error.

I am attempting to POST this student object into my Database.

My StudentController class is set up like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "api/v1/student")
public class StudentController {

    private final StudentService studentService;

    @Autowired
    public StudentController(StudentService studentService) {
        this.studentService = studentService;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public List<Student> getStudents(){
        return studentService.getStudents();
    }

    @PostMapping
    public void registerNewStudent(@RequestBody Student student){
        studentService.addNewStudent(student);
    }
}
```

My StudentService class is set up like this:

```
@Service
public class StudentService {

    private final StudentRepository studentRepository;

    @Autowired
    public StudentService(StudentRepository studentRepository) {
        this.studentRepository = studentRepository;
    }

    public List<Student> getStudents() {
        return studentRepository.findAll();
    }

    public void addNewStudent(Student student) {
        Optional<Student> studentOptional = studentRepository.findStudentByEmail(student.getEmail());
        if (studentOptional.isPresent()){
            throw new IllegalStateException(("email taken"));
        }
        studentRepository.save(student);
    }
}
```

My StudentConfig class is set up like this:

```
@Configuration
public class StudentConfig {

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(StudentRepository repository){
        return args -> {
            Student david = new Student(
                    "David",
                    "drob@apple.com",
                    LocalDate.of(1985, NOVEMBER, 3)
            );

            Student alex = new Student(
                    "Alex",
                    "alex@apple.com",
                    LocalDate.of(1995, JANUARY, 1)
            );

            repository.saveAll(List.of(david, alex));
        };
    }
}
```

Then StudentRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT s FROM Student s WHERE s.email = ?1")
    Optional<Student> findStudentByEmail(String email);
}
```

Last, the Student class:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Student {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "student_sequence",
            sequenceName = "student_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "student_sequence"
    )
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private LocalDate dob;
    @Transient
    private Integer age;

    public Student(Long id, String name, String email, LocalDate dob) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public Student(String name, String email, LocalDate dob) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public Student() {

    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public LocalDate getDob() {
        return dob;
    }

    public void setDob(LocalDate dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {

        return Period.between(this.dob, LocalDate.now()).getYears();
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", dob=" + dob +
                ", age=" + age +
                '}';
    }
}
```

I set up the project using SpringInitializr

Comment: you need to post a [mcve] in the question.

Comment: thank you OldProgrammer for your response.  I have updated the post.

Comment: `Server: nginx/1.23.0`, so you have a nginx web server in front of your Spring Boot app ?

Comment: Can you disable nginx?

Comment: @PeterMmm I'm wondering if the value of  `path` in `RequestMapping` requires `/` in the beginning?

Comment: No leading `/` slash required. But check, if  your Spring Boot app really listen (started) on port 8080. From the response, it seems there is another nginx server listen on this port (or it is not configured to forward to the Spring Boot app).

Comment: I had an nginx server running from a different project.  Was my first time setting up nginx before.  I didn't realize that after closing that project, it would continue to run.  Issue is now resolved.  Thank you @PeterMmm and Daniyar for pointing this out.  I guess the error message was pretty clear as to the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to turn off nginx server that was still on from another project with:
sudo nginx -s stop

Thank you @PeterMmm and @Daniyar Myrzakanov for pointing this out